# using connection string at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have created my model using database first approach. The issue is that my connection string changes at runtime. Therefore I have added an overloaded constructor for the DBContext class that takes connection string.

```
public partial class MyDataContext: DbContext
    {
        public MyDataContext: ()
            : base("name=DbEntities")
        {
        }

        // added this overloaded contructor
        public MyDataContext: (string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
```

The connection string that I get at runtime is like below.

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;initial catalog=MyDatabase;Max Pool Size=100;Min Pool Size=20;Connect Timeout=15;
```

Howover when I run a query using MyDataContext that is created using overloaded constructor, I get following error.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: 
>   The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was
>   generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First
>   development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not
>   remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use
>   Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is included in the app.config or
>   web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own
>   DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not
>   some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the
>   base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more
>   about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity
>   Framework documentation here:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

Any idea how this could be accomplished?

Comment: I suggest to start working from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i believe you need to include the metadata around the connection string when you're using an EDMX.  Just look at the `DbEntities` connection string that was generated and go off that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an EntityConnectionString and pass that one to your DbContext. You are currently only using an SqlConnectionString. I suggest you take a look at [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This is an example which you could use for an Sql Database First approach;

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlStringBuilder.Database = "database name":
sqlStringBuilder.Password = "password";
sqlStringBuilder.UserID = "userid";
// other properties

EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entityStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
entityStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.MySqlClient";
entityStringBuilder.Metadata = "resx//*/YourDbContext.csdl|resx//*/YourDbContext.ssdl|resx//*/YourDbContext.msl";

MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext(entityStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Just to be clear its a SQL Sever database. My EF connection string is now coming as metadata=resx://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;initial catalog=MyDatabase;Max Pool Size=100;Min Pool Size=20;Connect Timeout=15;"
But I get following error when run a query.
"At least one of the input paths is not valid because either it is too long or it has incorrect format." Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You should replace the metadata with correct metadata; usually it is something like `resx//*/YourDbContext.csdl|resx//*/YourDbContext.ssdl|resx//*/YourDbContext.msl`. You can probably find the correct metadata in your App.config. I'll update it in the answer.